# Defining an array with one type, but not mixed types

Tags: typescript

I want to type an array which may only hold **either** numbers **or** strings. but not the both.

The following syntax results in making the array accepts numbers **and** strings:

```
const arr: (string | number)[] = [];
arr.push(1);
arr.push("yellow");
```

The following syntax doesn't work, and my code editor is showing me errors:

```
const arr: (string[] | number[]) = [];
arr.push(1)
arr.push('yellow')
```

[image]

Comment: If you have a basket that can hold **either** apples **or** oranges (assume it's magical and would cannot hold both), then what you're trying to do in the second case is still add apple *and* orange. Even though you don't know which one the basket can take. That simply cannot work if you're throwing in items blindly.

Comment: Yep, it cannot work as @VLAZ said. You can cast it to `Array<string>` or `Array<number>` whenever you need.

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: I agree with previous commenters; it's not clear why you expect there not to be errors.  I can almost imagine expecting that the first `push()` would work and the second one would fail, but if that's what you expect then you'd still want to see an error, right?  Could you [edit] the question to demonstrate exactly where you think errors should and should not appear?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try like this

```
type arrayType = (string | number)[];
const arrayOfThings: arrayType = [];

const addToArray(value: string | number): void {
  if(arrayOfThings.length === 0) {
     arrayOfThings.push(value);}
  else if(typeof arrayOfThings[0] === typeOf value) { 
     arrayOfThings.push(value)
  }
  return;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Everything is possible in the run-time. But the purpose of typescript in the first-place was to help us in such things. It works of course, but not in development/compile time, but in the runtime.

Comment: @Normal the compile-time logic is contradictory. That's why it doesn't work. It's not TS, really, but the fact that you are trying to give it instructions that simply cannot be logically followed.

Comment: But @VLAZ, think of it from the other side, this is exactly the job of typescript, to tell us about such mistakes. You can of course define a variable `let a: number` and then assign it a string and it will work. But Typescript will show you a warning about it.

Comment: @Normal And you're getting an error. Because the logic is contradictory. [I've thought about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75371633/defining-an-array-with-one-type-but-not-mixed-types/75371816?noredirect=1#comment132993992_75371633) - have *you*?